# c++ Hole punching UDP(RTP)

Tags: c++, network-programming, udp, rtp, hole-punching

I am doing a client-server voice chat program(unmanaged C++,win32) in which clients connects to the server using TCP and textchat/chatroom functions are done in TCP while all audiotransmission is sent through a separate UDP/RTP socket (using the API from JRTPLIB).

So the IP is known from the TCP connection, and the port number of the RTP socket can be sent after connection is established.

The problem is that in TCP only the server needs to do port forwarding for communications to work both ways since you establish a connection, while in UDP you'd have to use recvfrom() -- which afaik needs the ports to be opened in the first place on the client side, which I do not want (and is not needed if you look at any multiplayer game or VoIP client)

Reading on sources that talk about UDP Hole Punching (for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching) for example they keep mentioning starting a udp conversation with the server. That's the thing - how do you actually start a udp conversation(both ways) with the server without the client having to open any ports? in TCP as I mentioned you just need to connect() to the server and communication is possible both ways.

Also -- I know RTP builds on UDP but is there anything else I should know about the RTP hole punching (again, using JRTPLIB) that makes it differ from UDP?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm slightly confused - UDP Hole Punching is done for NAT Traversal i.e. when you need to connect peer to peer and both peers are sat behing a private network ( or router ). The server is only used as a way of 'matchmaking' the two clients. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve UDP/RTP connection between clients connected to a server without having the clients open any ports. As I understand it, the clients exchange IP/Ports with the server who then shares it out between the clients so they can communicate to each other directly

Comment: What do you mean by "opening any ports" ? There have to be ports opened for them to communicate,that's what udp hole punching does.

Comment: How does online games and ventrilo/skype enable communication then? In those applications you don't need to open any ports for UDP communication

Comment: @KaiserJohaan I see why you might think that. Each client opens a port to the server. The server now has a 'traversable' path back through the NAT to the internal client. The server then sends the endpoint details to each client who then use that IP/Port to communicate. So the port is not re-opened for the peer to peer comms.

Comment: @zebrabox: Yes, I see now I got the definition of hole punching wrong. The port used in the connection phase to the server is the same as the one used in transfer phase between clients. Anyway if I can salvage the thread, the problem I described with applications(games, VOIP,etc) communicating over UDP without opening ports still puzzles me.

Comment: @KaiserJohaan - I'd recommend looking at the code in libjingle which is Google's peer to peer lib http://code.google.com/apis/talk/libjingle/index.html

Comment: @KaiserJohaan Many of them simply communicate through the server, in which case there is no problem. It's when the clients have to communicate directly you have to start tricking the nat gateways. That's described in the wikpedia page you linked, as well as e.g. http://www.brynosaurus.com/pub/net/p2pnat/ , http://www.brynosaurus.com/pub/net/internet-drafts/draft-ford-midcom-p2p-01.txt. An actual implementation for doing this is non trivial.

Comment: @nos Indeed - NAT Traversal is not possible for certain types of NAT conifguration so in those cases you either need to go through a relay server or not support those NAT types. As you say, implementing it is very non-trivial!

Comment: I see, so the communication is to be relayed through the server. But again, for the client, how can they receive data with udp From the server without actually opening ports, like its done through TCP with connect()?

Comment: When the client talks to the server in order to exchange port information, a connection is opened on both the client and NAT device.  If you have a well-behaved NAT device, that same connection can be used by the peer client to connect back.  At that point, communication is no longer relayed through the server.

Comment: @KaiserJohaan the client has to send the first UDP packet. That "opens" the port in the clients gateway, so it can receive data from the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible definitions of "opening a port". One is opening a port with bind() for UDP or listen() for TCP, another one is opening a port in a firewall.

You need to open a port with an API call in order to receive something, there is no way around it, but you probably realize this, so I think you mean opening a port in a firewall. But you don't need to do this on the side that initiates communication (the client). This applies both to TCP and UDP, unless your firewall is set up in a very paranoid mode. Any reasonable firewall would allow a response from a server to a UDP port if there was a datagram sent from this port to the same server some time before. You only need hole punching if both sides are behind NATing firewalls/routers. That's how Skype does it.

Moreover, you don't even have to bother with recvfrom() and such stuff. You can just bind() a UDP socket, then use connect() and recv()/send() or read()/write() exactly in the same way as you'd do with TCP.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. For the client, does connect() setup this connection or do you actually have to send() something for the firewall to thereafter accept incomming packets on that port?

Comment: @Kaiser, no, since UDP is a connectionless protocol, all the connect() call does is just set up the default address to send or receive so you don't have to specify it each time. So you have to send() something first.

Comment: I see. Thank you, am going to try this out!