# How to share images between 2 users directly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I am a newbie, please be lenient towards me. Please let me elaborate.

**Goal**

Transfer Data(images, files) between devices.

**What I am doing?**

1. Sending the file to server
2. Sending path to the other user
3. the other user starts to download the image from the path.

**Problem**

I need to make the file transfer direct between devices and minimize the role of the server as far as possible.

> P.S: I am trying to build a screen share COCOA app like we do in SKYPE calling. I
>   am thinking of sharing screenshots as quickly as
>   possible.
>   Any suggestions are most welcome. Please let me know if my approach is good or bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Multipeer Connectivity Framwork that support for discovering services provided by nearby iOS devices.

Refrence : (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/)

Comment: sir, the api is only for streaming data between only near by devices. However, for my need is to share data between devices at longer distance.

Answer (score 0):

I have no personal experience with this, but you should try to use [UPnP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play). It has to be enabled on the firewall for at least one device, so it can open an external port. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237604/point-to-point-network-connection-through-firewalls) thread. The devices would use the server to tell each other where they can be reached and then switch to that direct connection.

There are also other [NAT Traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal) techniques.

Another possibility might be using IPv6, if both devices have an IPv6 address (but I have really no experience with that).